# Taghelpers without wild card in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers

As per Microsoft we have to use the below line to add Tag Helpers.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Here, they have used `*` as a wild card. This means it imports all tag helpers from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` assembly. Correct me if I am wrong.

I don't want to use `*`. I only want to use asp-append-version for my Image.

What should I write instead of `*`?

Comment: As the official [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0) show you: `@addTagHelper AuthoringTagHelpers.TagHelpers.EmailTagHelper, AuthoringTagHelpers` - specify the fully qualified class name of the tag helper, plus its namespace, to reference only a single tag helper explicitly

Comment: Thanks, but what should I write if I have to use "asp-append-version" in my image without a wild card. Didn't find any document on the MS page.

Answer (score 2):

It will work like this.

```
@addTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ImageTagHelper ,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

You can follow below git hub page, where you can get the class name of all built-in tag helpers. Hope this will help someone.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers